# SSH to EC2 Instance is throwing error "no-supported-authentication-methods-available-server-sent-public-key"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh

I have an ec2-instance having private ip only to which I am logging in from RDP(remote desktop)  after connecting to VPN. The putty supported format PPK file is loaded in the pageant key list. Also the public key is placed in /etc/ssh/ path of root user. Please let me know what am I missing here which is not allowing login. The security group is also configured for port 22. Any valuable inputs is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Is the key in the correct format as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/204400/ssh-public-key-no-supported-authentication-methods-available-server-sent-publ)?

Comment: It looks like you are using public key to ssh instead of private key. did you generate the key file by yourself?

Answer (score 0):

**for me solution was to login as "ubuntu" rather than "ec2-user"**

ubuntu is the username for instance launched with ubuntu os,
ec2-user is the username for instance launched with Amazon linux os